# Query works in phpMyAdmin and in Chrome, but not in Safari

Tags: php, mysql

This query runs in both Chrome and phpMyAdmin, but fails in Safari: I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.

```
SELECT r.like_dislike FROM ratings r
            LEFT JOIN lessons l ON
            l.lesson_id = r.lesson_id
            LEFT JOIN subjects s ON
            s.subject_id = l.subject_id
            WHERE l.teacher_id = 142
```

Sometimes r.like_dislike is NULL, so I have run this, but still same issue:

```
    SELECT IFNULL(r.like_dislike,0) FROM ratings r
            LEFT JOIN lessons l ON
            l.lesson_id = r.lesson_id
            LEFT JOIN subjects s ON
            s.subject_id = l.subject_id
            WHERE l.teacher_id = 142
```

Comment: the querry has NOTHING to do with the browers

Comment: @Dagon you are right -- had to do with whether or not a user was logged-in